# MOVE-TO expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead runtime error

Tags: netlogo

When i try to create agents on separate groups of patches in radius that they own, i get a runtime error.

I looked for answers on here, but I do not fully understand them. Using if any? is often what people do. How could i implement that here or what else can i do?

```
to set-farm-in-radius [d]
 move-to one-of patches with [not any? other patches in-radius d with 
[belongs-to !=    nobody]]
 set farm patches in-radius farm-size
 ask farm [set belongs-to myself]
 let c random 6 + 61
 ask farm [set pcolor c]
end
```

I expected this to work, because the move-to one-of patches command appeared to be really easy.

Comment: whenever asking a question, instead of saying "I get a runtime error", always supply the complete, exact text of the error message. it makes helping you easier.

Comment: Apologies. I put that in the title, but i see now that it is not very clear like this. Thanks.

Comment: oh, ha, I missed that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, `move-to one-of patches` is a pretty safe command, it should never fail when run in a turtle context.

But you're doing something more involved:

```
move-to one-of patches with [not any? other patches in-radius d with [belongs-to != nobody]]
```

So `patches with [not any? other patches in-radius d with [belongs-to != nobody]]` can give an agentset with 0 patches in it.  And `one-of` an empty agentset is going to give you `nobody`.

So something like this might work better:

```
let open-patches patches with [not any? other patches in-radius d with [belongs-to != nobody]]
ifelse (any? open-patches) [
  move-to one-of open-patches
  set farm patches in-radius farm-size
  ask farm [set belongs-to myself]
  let c random 6 + 61
  ask farm [set pcolor c]
] [
  ; handle the case where there are no open patches...
]
```

Note that with your code as written, it looks pretty easy for all "farms" to get taken and leave no suitable open spaces, depending on how many turtles you have.